# How do I extraxt a value from a "key1=value1,key2=value2" list?

Tags: macros, strings, key-value, parsing, comma-separated-list

I have a comma-separated list of `key=value` strings. I want to extract the value based on the key. Something a bit like

```
\LookUpValue{c}{a=foo,b=bar,c=baz,d=zyyzx}{error:notfound}
```

The intention is that this would result in the string `baz`.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could define a custom key-value parser (assuming that the set of keys should be variable):

```
\documentclass{article}

\makeatletter
\def\LookUpValue#1#2#3{%
  \@tempswafalse
  \gdef\LookUpValue@false{#3}%
  \xdef\@tempa{#1}%
  \LookUpValue@#2,\@end,}
\def\LookUpValue@#1,{%
  \ifx#1\@end
    \if@tempswa\@tempc\else\LookUpValue@false\fi
  \else
    \LookUpValue@@#1\@nil\expandafter\LookUpValue@\fi}
\def\LookUpValue@@#1=#2\@nil{%
  \edef\@tempb{#1}%
  \ifx\@tempa\@tempb\gdef\@tempc{#2}\@tempswatrue\fi
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\LookUpValue{c}{a=foo,b=bar,c=baz,d=zyyzx}{error:notfound}

\textit{\LookUpValue{d}{a=foo,b=bar,c=baz,d=zyyzx}{error:notfound}}

\LookUpValue{e}{a=foo,b=bar,c=baz,d=zyyzx}{error:notfound}
\end{document}
```

[image: output]

## Addendum I

If you have a look at the answer of @egreg there is this very nice feature that allows you to store the result of `\LookUpValue` into a macro without printing it. Here is a way to achieve this in LaTeX2e (given my main solution):

```
\documentclass{article}

\makeatletter
\def\LookUpValue{\kernel@ifnextchar[\@LookUpValue{\@LookUpValue[\@tempa]}}
\def\@LookUpValue[#1]#2#3{%
  \@tempswafalse
  \begingroup
    \escapechar\m@ne
    \xdef\luv@namespace{\string#1}%
  \endgroup
  \xdef\reserved@a{#2}%
  \expandafter\LookUpValue@#3,\@end,}
\def\LookUpValue@#1,{%
  \ifx#1\@end
    \if@tempswa\@nameuse{@tempa}\let\@tempa\relax
      \expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\@gobble\fi%
  \else
    \LookUpValue@@#1\@nil\expandafter\LookUpValue@\fi}
\def\LookUpValue@@#1=#2\@nil{%
  \edef\reserved@b{#1}%
  \ifx\reserved@a\reserved@b\@namedef{\luv@namespace}{#2}\@tempswatrue\fi
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\LookUpValue{c}{a=foo,b=bar,c=baz,d=zyyzx}{error:notfound}

\def\mypreset{a=foo,b=bar,c=baz,d=zyyzx}
\LookUpValue[\myval]{d}{\mypreset}{}

\LookUpValue{e}{a=foo,b=bar,c=baz,d=zyyzx}{error:notfound}

\textsc{\myval}
\end{document}
```

## Addendum II

However, if the set of keys which values you try to extract is fixed throughout your document there is this simpler way:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{keyval}

\makeatletter
\newcommand\newspraffkey[1]{\define@key{spraffkeys}{#1}{\@namedef{value_of_#1}{##1}}}
\newcommand\LookUpValue[2]{%
  \begingroup
  \setkeys{spraffkeys}{#2}%
  \@nameuse{value_of_#1}%
  \expandafter\ifx\csname value_of_#1\endcsname\relax\else\expandafter\@gobbleaftergroup\fi
  \endgroup
}
\def\@gobbleaftergroup{\aftergroup\@gobble}
\makeatother

\newspraffkey{a}
\newspraffkey{b}
\newspraffkey{c}
\newspraffkey{d}

\begin{document}
\LookUpValue{c}{a=foo,b=bar,c=baz,d=zyyzx}{error:notfound}

\LookUpValue{d}{a=foo,b=bar,c=baz}{error:notfound}

\LookUpValue{e}{a=foo,b=bar,c=baz,d=zyyzx}{error:notfound}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

A version with filling up a `property` list using `expl3` syntax and looking for the relevant key-value -pair. Perhaps not the fastest way, but quite easy to use.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{xparse}


\ExplSyntaxOn
\cs_generate_variant:Nn \prop_put:Nnn {Nxn,Nxx}
\NewDocumentCommand{\LookUpValue}{mmm}{%
  \seq_set_from_clist:Nn \l_tmpa_seq {#2}
  \seq_map_inline:Nn \l_tmpa_seq {% Mapping through the sequence
    \seq_set_split:Nnn \l_tmpb_seq {=} {##1} 
    % Filling the property list
    \prop_put:Nxx \l_tmpa_prop {\seq_item:Nn \l_tmpb_seq {1}} {\seq_item:Nn \l_tmpb_seq {2}}
  }
  % Look if #1 is in the property list and display the value, otherwise #3
  \prop_if_in:NnTF \l_tmpa_prop {#1} {\prop_item:Nn \l_tmpa_prop {#1}} {#3}
}
\ExplSyntaxOff


\begin{document}

\LookUpValue{c}{a=foo,b=bar,c=baz,d=zyyzx}{error:notfound}

\LookUpValue{foobar}{a=foo,b=bar,c=baz,d=zyyzx}{error:notfound}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The following code uses the key-value functions in `expl3`; here I exploit “unknown keys”, something better can be done if the keys are known in advance.

If an optional argument is given, it should be a control sequence that will be (re)defined to the result.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xparse}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand{\LookUpValue}{ommm}
 {
  \str_set:Nn \l_spraff_given_key_str { #2 }
  \tl_clear:N \l_spraff_output_tl
  \keys_set:nn { spraff/random } { #3 }
  \tl_if_empty:NT \l_spraff_output_tl
   {
    \tl_set:Nn \l_spraff_output_tl { #4 }
   }
  \IfNoValueTF{#1}
   { \tl_use:N \l_spraff_output_tl }
   { \tl_set_eq:NN #1 \l_spraff_output_tl }
 }

\keys_define:nn { spraff/random }
 {
  unknown .code:n =
   \str_if_eq:NNT \l_spraff_given_key_str \l_keys_key_tl
    {
     \tl_set:Nn \l_spraff_output_tl { #1 }
    }
 }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\LookUpValue{c}{a=foo,b=bar,c=baz,d=zyyzx}{error:notfound}

\LookUpValue{e}{a=foo,b=bar,c=baz,d=zyyzx}{error:notfound}

\LookUpValue[\temp]{a}{a=foo,b=bar,c=baz,d=zyyzx}{error:notfound}

\texttt{\meaning\temp}

\end{document}
```

[image]